# What exactly is the security model of pass?

Tags: password-management, gnupg

Linux [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/) is a program that lets you store passwords in regular text files, which you it then encrypts with your GPG key.

I'm confused at how this is considered secure. The GPG key has a passphrase but looks like it normally gets cached in the agent, so you very rarely need to enter it. Usually, `pass some/password` just works.

But then, couldn't any other program running on your computer also run `pass bank` and steal your passwords?

Is this just for people who don't encrypt their entire hard drive or have multiple people sharing a computer (with different Linux users)? What are the major things pass tries to protect your passwords from, and things that it doesn't try to protect from?

Comment: "normally gets cached in the agent" -- that's a choice. You're free to make a different one. It's very common, f/e, to have one's private key on a yubikey or smartcard in a reader with a button that needs to be touched to authorize an operation.

Comment: Even if the password is cached by the agent, a non-root user other than your user will not have an easy time getting that state out of the agent. Also, you may not be using the agent, or may use a different configuration that doesn’t allow caching or requires some secondary mechanism to make the key available.

Answer (score 5):

It's always worth considering *what* you're protecting against.

The *major* threat today is that site A has a leak, so the credentials used for site A becomes public - and that the user has used same credentials for site B, which is of higher value.

Password management tools protect against this by letting you set unique passwords for A and B, without having to remember them. Almost anything will protect against this; even yellow notes on your keyboard.

It's probably correct that it won't protect against an attacker with access to your computer - but that's not a very typical threat. That's the exception, and protecting against someone who has full access to your computer is *extremely* difficult anyway; it's trivial to dump memory of a process or attach a debugger to read secrets.

So it protects against attackers that doesn't have access to your computer.

Comment: "worth considering what you're protecting against" - yes, that's the question, I am asking what `pass` is supposed to protect against.

Comment: Nothing, it's a piece of software that can be deployed in various ways depending on what the user wants to protect against. Caching of passphrase is one tuneable.

Comment: "protects against attackers that doesn't have access" - well, if I just put my passwords in a plain text file without encrypting, isn't that the same? My computer doesn't have sshd running and there's no way to access it from the internet, so there's no danger from attackers without access.

Comment: Pass is a tool. You have to fit it into your security model. The authors may have certain ideas, and I have certain ideas, but ultimately it's up to the user.

Comment: It's obviously not the same. Storing your passwords in an unencrypted file does nothing to protect you against physical attacks, e.g. theft of your storage drive/laptop/desktop/mobile.

Comment: For future readers: I have decided not to mark this answer as accepted, because it does not appear to actually answer the question. I am happy to consider other answers.

Comment: What answer are you seeking? `pass` is a tool, and the security model may differ between users.

Comment: Sorry, these comments have a very small limit so I can't really explain in more detail, but there are three sentences ending with `?` in my question. I would ideally look for an answer that directly addresses all three.